# How to print a good looking list with or without pandas while scraping with selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, export-to-csv

```
import pandas as pd
import geocoder
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://prisguiden.no/kategorier/mobiltelefon")

variant = driver.find_element_by_class_name("category-results").text
pris = driver.find_element_by_class_name ("price-low")

print (variant)
```

This gives me all the info i want, it is just not a good presentation of my data.
I have googled some pandas lists but it wont work, in the end i want to export my data to readable tables in excel or similar.

Comment: "it is just not a good presentation of my data" -- what exactly is it printing, and what format do you want it in?

Comment: Well its python print, so ABC123 or A1B2C3 etc. Instead of something like:
A 1
B 2
C 3 in colums or rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to scrape some data from a webpage and clean it up so it's in a useable format.

The data you have scraped is a set of mobile phones, you could separate these by brand name, then find extract the properties of each phone from there. The number of properties per phone is not always equal so some *fiddling* is needed ...

Here's a start

```
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver 


def get_data():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'<pathtodriver>') 
    driver.get("https://prisguiden.no/kategorier/mobiltelefon")

    variant = driver.find_element_by_class_name("category-results").text 
    pris = driver.find_element_by_class_name ("price-low")

    return variant.split("\n")


def split_data(txt):
    brand = ["Apple", "Sony", "Samsung", "Huawei", "Xiaomi", "OnePlus"]
    prods = []
    prod = []
    for item in txt:
        if item in brand:
            if len(prod) > 0:
                prods.append(prod)
            prod = [item]
        else:
            prod.append(item)
    return prods


class Product:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.brand = args[0]
        self.model = args[1]
        self.spec = args[2]
        self.price = [a for a in args if 'priser' in a][0]
        self.other_info = [a for a in args 
                           if a not in (self.brand,
                                        self.model,
                                        self.spec,
                                        self.price)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data()
    li = split_data(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame([Product(*l).__dict__ for l in li])
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i wil test this.

Comment: When you do this [] as in f.ex; prods = [] - what does it do when it doesnt have any information?

Comment: @larsmath not sure I understand what you mean? You could do a check to see `data` is not `None` ?

Comment: prods = []
    prod = [] 

Does these mean anything, or are they blank for me to fill in?

Comment: @larsmath `get_data()` uses your code to scrape the webpage and return a list of data items. If you `print(get_data())` you will see the data that corresponds to each mobile phone that was listed on the webpage. For every phone, the first data item is the brand name. I thought this was a good way to split your data. Therefore `split_data()` takes the list of data items and transforms it to a list of lists where items relating to different phones are in different lists.

Comment: @larsmath In the code, `prods` is the list of lists and `prod` is a list that gets filled up until the data item is a brand name at which point the `prod` gets added to `prods` and then `prod` gets reset for the next mobile phone. Does that make sense? Put a couple of print statements `print(prod)` and `print(prods)` at the start of the for loop if you want to see how the lists are populated.

Comment: Nice explanation! :) If i understand it correctly; prods and prod [] are left empty for the script to fill in while scraping?

Comment: @larsmath, Yes that is correct. Well, strictly speaking, the scraping is done and returned. Then, the returned data is processed into the list of list as described above. Have you managed to test out the script?